# link two wifi systems

Tags: wifi, bridge

My neighbor and I would like to share several rpi surveillance cameras. They are all on distinct and separate IP addresses. Question: how can we each see each others IP cameras from our own wifi network? For example my rpi camera is on IP 192.168.1.199 on my wifi xxx and his rpi camera is on IP 192.168.1.198 on his wifi zzz.

Comment: You have to connect the (internet) router on one subnet to the router on the other subnet and use routing. There is no Raspberry Pi involved for this. You should better ask at https://superuser.com/users/879258/

Comment: Its impossible to achieve this with routing since they are likely on the same IP subnet (192.168.1.[198-199]) ! An more advanced setup with portforwarding and NAT is possible but tedious and complex. To switch subnet on one location and then add routing as described above is a more feasible solution.